# How to import children() to Helper in CakePHP 2.0?

Tags: function, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, children, helper

I was about making generate link of whole children. Because View doesnt allow to use Model. That's why i have to making own Helper to generate. then I use `$this->Model->children($current_id, false, 'category');` but the problem i got error like this

> Fatal error: Call to a member function children() on a non-object in
>   /user/app/View/Helper/my_helper.php on line 193

My code:

```
<?php
class MyHelperHelper extends AppHelper {
    var $helpers = array('Html','Paginator','Tree');

    function makechildrenlink($current_id, $category_id, $item_id) {
        $this->Category->children($current_id, false, 'category');




    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Why are you using the view layer to fetch data from the model? Let the controller/component do that and pass it down to the helper. Also, `my_helper.php` is not how the file name looks like in cake 2.x

Comment: my_helper.php is I made my own helper like tools. Because there is many item to use function from that one my_helper.php but Helper cant use children() to make list of all children of Parent.

Comment: Geeze - `$this->Category`. How could this possibly work if you never declared what this is supposed to be in this helper? PHP is not magic. CakePHP is so some degree, but not that much either.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller/component scope you need to fetch the data:

```
$this->loadModel('Category');
$categories = $this->Category->children($current_id, false, 'category');
$this->set(compact('categories')); // pass it down to the view
```

In the view you can now do with $categories whatever you want

```
echo $this->MyHelper->makeChildrenLink($categories);
```

for example.

And, as stated in the comments, your helper needs to be `View/Helper/MyHelper.php`!

Comment: but each item need use function. all of them is different category.

Comment: you can iterate over items - foreach is your friend.